# What geometric/trigonometric reasoning was used to deduce that $\theta_1 = \theta_0 - \theta$ and $(-\theta_2) = \theta_0 + \theta$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, physics

I have the following figure from *Fundamentals of Photonics, Third edition*, by Saleh and Teich:

> [image]

The accompanying explanation says the following:

> The angle $\theta_2$ is negative since the ray is traveling downward. Since the three angles of a triangle add to $180^\circ$, we have $\theta_1 = \theta_0 - \theta$ and $(-\theta_2) = \theta_0 + \theta$, so that $(-\theta_2) + \theta_1 = 2 \theta_0$. ...

What geometric/trigonometric reasoning (besides the obvious fact that the angles of a triangle add to $180^\circ$) was used to deduce that $\theta_1 = \theta_0 - \theta$ and $(-\theta_2) = \theta_0 + \theta$? It seems to me to be some theorem of similar triangles with a bisector angle (although, it's not clear that the angles on either side of the line splitting $\theta$ are equal), but I'm unsure.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: $\theta_1+\theta+(180-\theta_0)=180\;$ Then $\;\theta_1=\theta_0-\theta\;$ Same for $\theta_2\;$. The negative sign is a matter of convenience.

Comment: @Ripi2 I don't think that's correct. It seems that $\theta_1 + \theta + (180^\circ - \theta_0)$ double-counts the angle embedded in $\theta$ for the smaller triangle?

Comment: Look closer at the image.The angle at the mirror is $2\theta$ not just $\theta$.

Comment: @Ripi2 Ohh, you're right; that's why they wrote $\theta$ twice. My apologies!

Comment: @Ripi2 How is it the same for $\theta_2$? The triangle that contains the angle $\theta_2$ has a curved side, so its angles don't sum to $180^\circ$?

Comment: Curved side? Cannot be. The triangle I'm looking at is the $CP_2Mirror$

Comment: @Ripi2 Oh, yes, I see now. For the second one, we have $$\begin{align} &[180^\circ - (\theta + \theta_0)] + \theta_2 = 180^\circ \\ &\Rightarrow \theta_2 = \theta + \theta_0 \\ &\therefore (-\theta_2) = \theta + \theta_0 \end{align}$$ I understand it all now. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this!